# Python Pandas why is there a discrepancy in percentage change when calculated manually?

Tags: python, pandas

Why does python pandas calculate a different value when typing formulas manually. For example:

```
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[256.143, 256.571]})

# Percent Change via method (correct value of 0.001671)
df['percent change'] = df['value'].pct_change()

# Percent Change manually (incorrect value of 0.001668)
df['percent change'] = df['value'].diff() / df['value']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `df['value'].diff()` you get a dataframe with two values, NaN for the first entry and 0.428 for the second entry. Then you divide it (element-wise) by the original dataframe, so you divide NaN by the first value (256.143) and 0.428 by the second value (256.571). In short, you're getting different results cause you're calculating different things.

With `df1['percent change'] = df1['value'].diff() / df1['value'][0]` you get the result you were expecting.

Comment: The [0] works well with two rows, but I have thousands. Is there a clean way to reference a previous row entry in pandas without using a for loop?

Answer (score 3):

It is because the difference is compared with the row before and you are dividing it by the second row. We can use `shift` to check this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[256.143, 256.571]})
df['percent change'] = df['value'].pct_change()
df['percent change2'] = df['value'].diff() / df['value'].shift()
```

**Output**

```
     value  percent change  percent change2
0  256.143             NaN              NaN
1  256.571        0.001671         0.001671
```